# call bash function with cmd argument to use it in a if statement

Tags: bash

I want to run a retry function that accepts as arguments an *operator* and a *cmd* in order to reuse the function.. e.g.

```
"-z" and "pgrep -f 'sleep 10'"
"! -z" and "pgrep -f 'sleep 10'"
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

retry() {
    local -r operator="$1"; shift
    local -r cmd="$@"

    retry_count=5
    attempts=0

    echo "run $cmd"
    #until [ $operator `pgrep -f 'sleep 10'` ] <---this works
    until [ $operator `${cmd}` ]
    do
        sleep $((++attempts))
        if [ $attempts -gt $retry_count ]; then
            echo "failed. exit with error"
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "try again ..."
    done
    
    echo "success"
}

retry "! -z" "pgrep -x 'sleep 10'"
retry "-z" "pgrep sleep"
```

I got this error message:

```
pgrep: only one pattern can be provided
Try `pgrep --help' for more information.
```

I am open to use a different approach.

Comment: Quotes embedded inside variables are literal data and don't have any special properties. The typical solution is to use an array - `local -r cmd=( "$@" )` and then `[ $operator $( "${cmd[@]}" ) ]`. See also [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Additionally the function call would be, for example, `retry "! -z" pgrep -x 'sleep 10'`

Comment: @tjm3772 your approach works fine. you could provide this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the first `retry` example, the single quotes are not interpreted anymore by the shell, because this would have to be done after parameter expansion. Therefore, the command `pgrep` gets called with the following three parameters:

```
-f
'sleep
10'
```

This would be equivalent to run `pgrep` with

```
pgrep "-f"   "'sleep"  "10'"
```

which should produce the same error message.

As a solution, I suggest that you define `cmd` as array instead of a scalar:

```
cmd=("$@")
```

and evaluate it as

```
[ $operator `${cmd[@]}` ]
```

or better avoid the obsolete backquotes and write

```
[ $operator $("${cmd[@]}") ]
```

Of course in your case, you can get rid of the variable and simply write

```
[ $operator $("$@") ]
```